# Base de datos de google maps

Tags: google-maps

Hola estoy necesitando tener el total de direcciones junto con sus números de puerta de una ciudad, estado, pais, etc.

Hay alguna forma de obtener estos datos desde google maps, alguna base de datos abierta, obtener toda las direcciones desde google maps?

Gracias

Comment: La pregunta es demasiado amplia y no hace mención del esfuerzo realizado previo a su publicación como es requerido por [ask].

Answer (score 2):

La API de Google Maps no ofrece esa posibilidad.

Sin embargo existe esta página web con una BD OpenSource con toda la información alrededor del mundo entero:
https://www.openstreetmap.org

Es la unica base de datos open source que he encontrado. Si en tu caso quieres el listado de direcciones solo para validar, podrías llamar a la api de google, y si no te devuelve nincuna localizaciom significaria que no existe.

Comment: Si pero que tan confiable es esa pagina?